# In Unity, how do I make the camera follow a character?

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, camera

When my character moves, I want the camera to follow them, such that the character always stays in the middle of the view. How do I do that in Unity?

---

Here's my code right now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControll : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 3f;

    private Animator animator;
    private Vector2 screenSW;
    private Vector2 screenNE;
    private float wrapPadding = 1f;
    public GameObject gameObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = this.GetComponent<Animator> ();

        screenSW = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2(0, 0));
        screenNE = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        if (horizontalInput == 0) {
            animator.speed = 0;
            animator.SetInteger("Direction", 0);
        }

        else if (horizontalInput < 0) {
            animator.speed = 3;
            animator.SetInteger("Direction", 1);
        }

        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        transform.Translate (Vector2.up * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        if (transform.localPosition.x < screenSW.x - wrapPadding) {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector2(screenNE.x, transform.localPosition.y);       
        }

        else if (transform.localPosition.x > screenNE.x + wrapPadding) {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector2(screenSW.x, transform.localPosition.y);       
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D other){



    }
}
```

Comment: your problem is related to the way you defining it. I can't understand what you asked

Comment: Sorry ... Summary, My camera is fixed & does't move when character goes out of the original camera size ...

Comment: do you want your camera to move only when character exits original camera size or you want the camera to stick with player in the middle?

Comment: Stick with player in the middle ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the main camera a child of the player object in the hierarchy, then move it to where you want it in the scene view with the translate/rotate tools. Don't make it overly complicated with code.

Or apply the same control scripts and colliders to the camera as to the player object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'll tell you what I came up with in my project.

attach a script to your Main camera object, declare a player like

```
public GameObject player;
```

initialize it in the `Start` function (be sure you set your character tag to "Player" in this case) like

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
```

and then in the `Update` (assuming your character is moving in the xy plane) just put

```
if(player != null)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, -10);
        }
else
{
    Debug.Log("Player not set correctly. Please check if tag is set correctly.");
}
```

Adjust the Z position to where you want the camera to be away from player (see if you need positive or negative values)

Comment: I attached a C# script & copy your codes, But it doesn't work ... (Also i renamed it to Player)

Comment: @Ali What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Ali that does work. Maybe you should add some detail, e.g. your game is 2d or 3d. it is a top down game? is you character moving on xy or xz plane?

Comment: @Leggy7 It doesn't work, There is no mean to this sentence ...

Comment: My game is 2d, No , XY ...